# How to add a fixed number to a particular attribute of a line in an XML file?

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file that contains several lines like this:

```
<Teste  Time="380643" TT="380592" Win="-2" Xl="28" Yl="55" />
<Teste  Time="380660" TT="380592" Win="-2" Xl="28" Yl="55" />
```

I need to add a fixed number to every instance of the `Time` attribute, e.g. `380643 + 10000`, and get an XML file with the new lines, e.g. `<Time="390643" TT="380592" Win="-2" Xl="28" Yl="55"/>`. Is this possible using Perl? If so, how? If not, what should I do?

Comment: You are right. Actually It would be something like this: <Teste Time="380643" TT="380592" Win="-2" Xl="28" Yl="55" />. Anyway alex-shesterov's answer has helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.42/Twig.pm) with `twig_roots`:

```
my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
  twig_roots => 
    { Time => sub { $_->set_att( TT => $_->att('TT')+10000 )->flush; } 
    },
  twig_print_outside_roots => 1 
);
$twig->parsefile('myXmlFile.xml');
```

Comment: by using `twig_roots => { Time   => sub { $_->set_att( TT => $_->att('TT')+10000 )->flush; }, twig_print_outside_roots => 1,` you don't need the final `print` and you will use much less memory (instead of the whole XMl file to be loaded in memory you only load the Time elements, and they're flushed after being used).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed. Just a further question: how can I write the script to add a number to TT and Win at the same time?

Comment: `Time => sub { 
  $_->set_att( TT => $_->att('TT')+10000, Win => $_->att('Win')+10000 )->flush; 
}` 
XML::Twig is indeed very powerful, read the docs on Cpan if you want to learn about its possibilities. Or just remember "XML::Twig" for XML processing in Perl, in case if you need it in future )

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# use module
use XML::Simple;

# create object
$xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
$data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml");

# access XML data
$time = $data->{Time}->TT;
//do your stuff here
```

More :  [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/parsing-xml-documents-with-perls-xmlsimple/5363190)